# SQL Select rows where created_at is greater than a date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am getting very odd results running the following query:

```
select * from "statuses" where "created_at" > '2015-04-26 02:04:24';
```

this seems to returning the following dates:

```
2015-04-26 10:44:04
2015-04-26 12:19:47
2015-04-26 12:20:12
```

as you can see these are actually below the specified DATE/TIME i entered. I assume that this has something to do with the formatting of the date?

How should my query look to get accurate results?

Comment: Those dates *are* greater than the date you specified. You probably mean to use `<` which will get you older dates.

Comment: below? how is 2015-04-26 12:20:12 below 2015-04-26 02:04:24?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have saved the data in `datetime` or `timestamp` then you are getting the correct result, the hour minute and second format is `H:i:s` i.e. 24 hours format.

So in the comparison

`created_at > '2015-04-26 02:04:24'`

`2015-04-26 02:04:24` means `2 AM +`
and the results you are getting are all greater than that

`10 AM, 12 PM` and so

If you are looking to find greater than `2 PM` then you need

`created_at > '2015-04-26 14:04:24'`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thanks to the commenters I have figured out what was going on, I didn't actually think to check the actual time value, but in my PHP script I was converting the timestamp to `h:m:s` this should have been `H:m:s` (24hr) and it is now producing the correct results.

Thanks for prompting me to check that, I can miss the simplest things sometimes.

Comment: Looks like that's illustrated in the answer below.  Are you answering your own question by copying his?

Comment: No, He replied as I was typing my answer, I am accepting his as it is correct.

Comment: lol.. this is not a competition for me to get my answer accepted.  I don't care about that, I only care about helping and since I tried this code myself and it worked I was just curious to understand why it might not be working for you.  I'm glad you found a solution